# cannot convert from const char* to const char *&

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I am writing a simple UTF8 to WideStr function on VC++.

MtoW.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
wstring UTF8toWide(const char*& in);
```

MtoW.cpp

```
#include "MtoW.h"
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;
wstring UTF8toWide(const char*& in) {
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in, -1, NULL, 0);
    wchar_t* wide_str = new wchar_t[size];
    int result_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in, -1, wide_str, size);
    assert(size == result_size);
    return wstring(wide_str);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "MtoW.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s = "hi";
    //s.c_str();
    //const char* q = "abc";
    //const char*& c = q;
    wstring q = UTF8toWide(s.c_str()); //error 
}
```

I got `cannot convert from const char* to const char *&` error, why?
`s.c_str()` is a `const char*` type and my code should work.

Comment: It looks like a memory leak in `UTF8toWide`: where is the `wchar_t[]` deleted?

Comment: @drRobertz :D I forgot to write that. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns is an rvalue, which can't be bound to an lvalue-reference to non-const (i.e. `const char*&`).

You can change the parameter type to `const char* in` or `const char* const & in` if `in` won't be modified in `UTF8toWide()`, or use a named variable instead.

```
string s = "hi";
const char* c = s.c_str();
wstring q = UTF8toWide(c);
```

Comment: Thank you. But why `const CharT* c_str() const;` look like this, I mean the latter `const`, does it mean that it's a member function of a class? Because AFAIK, only member function can have a `const` after function name.

Comment: @Rick Yes, it's a member function, a `const` member function.

Comment: Ok. But I still don't understand why it needs a `const char* const&`, the latter const. I know `const char* const&`, it's a **reference** of a **constant** pointer, and the pointer points to a const char.

Comment: @Rick That's because rvalue could be bound to reference to const, but not reference to non-const. e.g. you can write `const int& ri = 0;`, but can't write `int& ri = 0;`.

Comment: T-T, may I take up a few mins of you in stackoverflow chat?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to rvalue:

```
UTF8toWide(s.c_str());
           ^^^^^^^^^ this is rvalue
```

you need lvalue:

```
const char* c = s.c_str();
std::wstring q = UTF8toWide(c); //ok
```

or change UTF8toWide by removing reference, `const char* in` is ok

Answer (score 1):

In addition to changing the function, you have to address the memory leak caused by `new` operator. Call `delete[] wide_str;` before exiting the function, or use `std::wstring` to start with:

```
std::wstring UTF8toWide(const char* in) 
{
    if (!in)
        return std::wstring(L"");
    int size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in, -1, NULL, 0);
    std::wstring ws(size, L'\0');
    int result_size = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, in, -1, &ws[0], size);
    assert(size == result_size);
    return ws;
}

std::string s = u8"ελληνικά";
std::wstring q = UTF8toWide(s.c_str());
```

or use `#include <codecvt>` for C++11

```
wstring q = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>{ }.from_bytes(s);
```

Comment: Thanks +1. Btw, the document said `codecvt` has been deprecated since C++17.